# Swift : Error when saving to core data context

Tags: ios, swift, core-data, persistence

My app consist of two view managed by tab bar controller.

The first view contains a button that downloads data from server and parse it into objects. After that is done I create core data entities based on these objects. Anytime the button is pushed, the former entities are deleted to avoid adding the same data

The second view contains table view resposible for displaying the retrieved core data entities data.

This is my method to save data:

```
 func saveData()
    {

        var context:NSManagedObjectContext = self.managedObjectContext!
        var error: NSError?
        let entityDescription =
        NSEntityDescription.entityForName("Medicine",
            inManagedObjectContext: managedObjectContext!)

        for element in self.loadedArray {

            var medicine = Medicine(entity: entityDescription!,
                insertIntoManagedObjectContext: managedObjectContext)

            medicine.name = element.name
            medicine.desc = element.desc


            var error: NSError?

            context.save(&error)
            println(medicine)

        }

}
```

this is how I delete the data

```
    func deleteData() {


    let fetchRequest = NSFetchRequest(entityName: "Medicine")


    let fetchedEntities = self.managedObjectContext!.executeFetchRequest(fetchRequest, error: nil) as! [Medicine]

    for entity in fetchedEntities {
        self.managedObjectContext!.deleteObject(entity)
    }

    self.managedObjectContext!.save(nil)
}
```

I save the the data once the loadedArray from downloaded data is ready

```
 var loadedArray:[Drug] = [] {
    didSet {
        self.saveData()
    }
}
```

The behaviour is nondeterministic, but the error usually occurs when I save the data, then go to table view then go back to delete/save new data. This is when the crash happens and this is the error:

[image]

I am aware of the fact that this error is relatively hard to reproduce, so I think the best way is to provide a link to project
https://github.com/thedc89/MedApp (check out the latest commit)

Thanks in advance

EDIT:

this is fetched result controller in second view:

```
lazy var fetchedResultsController: NSFetchedResultsController = {
    let medicinesFetchRequest = NSFetchRequest(entityName: "Medicine")
    let primarySortDescriptor = NSSortDescriptor(key: "name.order", ascending: true)

    medicinesFetchRequest.sortDescriptors = [primarySortDescriptor]

    let frc = NSFetchedResultsController(
        fetchRequest: medicinesFetchRequest,
        managedObjectContext: self.managedObjectContext!,
        sectionNameKeyPath: "name",
        cacheName: nil)

    frc.delegate = self

    return frc
    }()
```

Moreover, for some reason the datamodel seems to be missing on github project which is really weird. However, if it was actually missing I think it would not save any data but it happens for the first time I touch the button

Comment: Have you deleted and reinstalled the app since you last made changes to the Schema?

Comment: hmm, don't know, I will try right now

Comment: Well, this does not solve the problem

Comment: I downloaded the project and you schema wasn't able to be opened. Have you setup the object graph correctly?

Comment: you cannot open my data model? this is weird, I don't have such problem, could you show a screenshot?

Comment: No. In fact the `xcdatamodel` is referenced by the Xcode project but the file itself isn't included in the bundle. It looks like it may have gotten deleted via finder? It's definitely not present though.

Comment: This is so weird, the file is present in my directory but in fact it's missing on github, this is so strange, but I think here it is https://github.com/thedc89/MedApp/tree/189a3bf3aa08e64d84c034e81cd6dd7b35dfd229/ReminderApp

Comment: I think the underlying problem has little or nothing to do with CoreData as the actual message indicates that a `NSString` is receiving `valueForUndefinedKey:@"order"` This kind of thing usually happens when you have dangling references to an object that aren't properly cleaned up, or when you are misinterpreting the class of an `NSObject`

Comment: I've summed up what I think your problem is in an answer. I hope it helps.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After downloading your project it looks like the `xcdatamodel` is missing, even though it is included with the Xcode project. Other answers on SO seem to confirm similar issues for the same error: [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12651860/nsunknownkeyexception-for-existing-and-non-mistyped-key) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10898716/unable-to-store-in-core-data-from-restkit-because-of-nsunknownkeyexception).

Additionally having a property named `order` is generic enough that it could be used internally. Try changing it to something like `itemSortOrder` or something more descriptive to avoid conflicts.

Comment: I've edited my question, I do not have any property called order, just the order in fetched results controller

Comment: If you don't have a property called `order` then you can't use `name.order`. As a key.

Comment: I changed name.order into name and now it works, this was pretty straightforward but I could not figure it out from this error:)